# How to disable the resize grabber of <textarea>?

Tags: html, css, forms

How to disable the grabber in the `<textarea>`?

I mean that triangle thing which appears in the right-bottom corner of the `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 1092, accepted):

Just use `resize: none`

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

You can also decide to resize your textareas only horizontal or vertical, this way:

`textarea { resize: vertical; }`

`textarea { resize: horizontal; }`

Finally,
`resize: both` enables the resize grabber.

Comment: IE doesn't allow resize of the text area therefore this will do the job as intended.

Comment: @anothershrubery Likewise with iOS Safari, and I imagine the other mobile browsers.

Comment: For the textarea tag - In the CSS be sure NOT to specify a width AND while also having cols specificied in the textarea tag because you may have a "user agent stylesheet" issue.

Answer (score 72):

```
<textarea style="resize:none" name="name" cols="num" rows="num"></textarea>
```

Just an example

Answer (score 12):

example of textarea for disable the resize option

```
<textarea CLASS="foo"></textarea>

<style>
textarea.foo
{
resize:none;
}

</style>
```