# Trying to remove resizable from textarea

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable resizable property of TextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)
>   [How to disable the resize grabber of an HTML <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271782/how-to-disable-the-resize-grabber-of-an-html-textarea)

I've inherited a website to maintain and I'm not able to remove the textarea to be resizable or at least to remove the resizable "flag". Here is what I mean :

[image]

How can I remove this? it's not problem if it's resizable the problem is this icon showing that it is.

Comment: if you want to do it inline just do <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" style="resize:none;"> text </textarea>

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to use [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) property to prevent the `textarea` to be resized.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/krwwY/)

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

---

`resize` property also takes values like `vertical` and `horizontal` to resize the `textarea` horizontally only, or vertically only.

**For Vertical only**

```
textarea { 
   resize:vertical; 
}
```

**For Horizontal only**

```
textarea { 
   resize:horizontal; 
}
```