# How to create a fixed size twitter bootstrap text area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I want to create a fixed sized text area which cannot be dragged to change the size. How can I make a text area fixed size in `Twitter Bootstrap`.
How can its size be fixed? By fixed size I mean fixed number of cols and rows.

I went through the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html) but didn't get any clue.

Comment: For the record, the Bootstrap documentation won't have everything you need to build your website. The Bootstrap docs help you work with the components and elements that are Bootstrap-specific. This question isn't really about Twitter Bootstrap at all; it's about HTML textareas in general. If run into more things like this that aren't documented in Bootstrap, it's probably because it's documented in the HTML or CSS specs. Here's a [relevant SO answer I got from Googling about textareas in general.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271782/how-to-disable-the-resize-grabber-of-an-html-textarea)

Comment: I totally agree on you.

Comment: Another good question closed by someone who didn't take the time to understand the question properly. Too bad the powah of reopen votes cost a lot of reputation. That this question was closed is BS imo.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could also set the css style width and min-width so as the height and min-height as well as max-width and max-height. just another suggestion.

```
textarea{ 
  width: 200px; 
  min-width:200px; 
  max-width:200px; 

  height:200px; 
  min-height:200px;  
  max-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 87):

Add this to your CSS:

```
textarea { resize:none; }
```

or this for fixed width (and keep vertical resizing):

```
textarea { resize:vertical; }
```

Note that this is [not supported by opera and internet explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize#Browser_compatibility).