# Disabling resize on Dijit Simple Text Area?

Tags: resize, textarea, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.9 to start learning, and I'm having trouble disabling the resize of the Simple Textarea. I don't really have a particular need to do this, I was just curious about how to and have since been unable.

There is no property listed in the Dijit API, and changing the CSS either with .set("style"), including it inline in the original container (I'm doing it programmatically), or even trying to set resize to none in the original declaration ie:

```
var textarea = new SimpleTextarea({
                rows: 5,
                cols: 10,
                onFocus: function(){ console.log("textarea focus handler"); },
                onBlur: function(){ console.log("textarea blur handler"); },
                selectOnClick: true,
                style: "resize=none",
                value: "This is a sample SimpleTextarea."
            }, "textarea");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271782/how-to-disable-the-resize-grabber-of-an-html-textarea. It can be done with CSS.

Comment: Thanks! Including this in the html file worked great...however it would be nice if I could it on an instance by instance basis in the creation of the textarea, but that doesn't seem to work. Solved for now!

Comment: Nothing stops you to pass on a "baseClass" attribute to the widget containing a CSS class which does this for you ;) This way you can still control it per instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you set style equal to an object with a key value pair of resize : "none" that will do the trick

```
var textarea = new SimpleTextarea({
      style: {resize : "none"}
}, "textarea");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<input dojotype="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea"
       id="yourTxtWidget"
       style="resize:none; width: 230px; height: 75px;"
       class="myTextField"/>
```