# Textarea stretches parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a textarea inside a fixed div.

My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/UY5B6/7/

You can see that the `textarea` stretches out the div. I just want the textarea to fill the div, not stretch it.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Is there any way you can show us what you *want* and how it is different from what you have?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative top margin to `textarea`.

```
div.modal a {
    position: relative; /* Show above textarea */
}
div.modal textarea {
    margin-top: -24px; /* Equal to 'close' height */
    padding-top: 24px; /* Equal to 'close' height */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now you can add borders to match your style.

You can also apply following css.

```
div.modal a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* Show above textarea */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
div.modal textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 24px; /* Equal to 'close' height */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong. You've set the width and height of the div to 50%, which considering that its parent element is the `<body>` element, seems logical that it appears the way it does. Are you trying to do something else?

edit: I think I see what you are talking about. The draggable resize part of the `textarea` element reaches outside of the div element. What you can do is, on the `textarea` element, put:

`textarea { resize: none; }`

to disable that and have it fit the div normally.

source: [How to disable the resize grabber of an HTML <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271782/how-to-disable-the-resize-grabber-of-an-html-textarea)