# Let user choose how many lines in a textarea to show [HTML] [JAVASCRIPT?]

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I let users choose (in a number field) how many lines of a textarea to show? I would have some demo code but unfortunately I just didn't know where to start.

Comment: It would be better to do this with JS than PHP (otherwise dual form processing would be required, and the PHP is doing something JS can).

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745741/auto-expanding-textarea . Though it's not exactly what you want, the gist should be clear. Instead of an event on the textarea, you set the event on the number input et voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qzr8ws6c/)

### HTML

```
Text area lines: <input id="lineNoInput" type="number" name="lines" value="2">
<br/><br/>
<textarea id="textArea" name="text" form="usrform" rows="2" cols="36">Enter text here...</textarea>
```

### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$('#lineNoInput').on("change paste keyup", function() {
    $('#textArea').attr('rows', $('#lineNoInput').val());
});
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is great, thanks, but I want to force users not to see anymore than X lines, because I can scroll down if there is more than X lines.

Comment: @Nerks You mean you don't want them to be able to adjust the size of the textbox?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly want I want.

Comment: @Nerks then just do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271782/how-to-disable-the-resize-grabber-of-an-html-textarea and don't forget to close your answer if you've figured it out

Comment: Thanks for the help!