# Angular 2+ - Limit textarea value in columns and rows

Tags: javascript, angular, events, 2-way-object-databinding

I am currently facing the following problem. I have a *`textarea`* and I want not only to limit the size of the *`textarea`* with the default attributes *`rows`* and *`cols`*, but I also want to prevent the user from entering more characters than the ones defined in those attributes. I have a somewhat working solution but I am not too happy with it. Maybe you have some suggestions how to improve the solution

**HTML**

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="10" (keyup)="limitTextArea($event)"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
limitTextArea(evt: KeyboardEvent) {

    let textarea = evt.target as any
    let maxRows: number = textarea.rows;
    let maxColumns: number = textarea.cols;

    let newContent: string = (textarea.value as string)
        .split('\n')
        .filter((val, row) => row < maxRows)
        .map(val => val.slice(0, maxColumns))
        .join('\n');

    textarea.value = newContent;
}
```

Now there are several problems with this solution.

1. It is being called by the `keyup`-Event. So the user will always see the character he or she typed before it disappears again.
2. I kind of mess around with the whole 2 way data binding principle by setting `textarea.value`
3. I am using `any` as Type for the *`textarea`* which I really don't like. If I am using TypeScript I want to use Types.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried maxlength and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271782/how-to-disable-the-resize-grabber-of-an-html-textarea?

Comment: maxlength unfortunately just limits the amount of characters in total. it doesnt care about the characters per line

Comment: col specifies the chars per line. btw, have you tried the link above?

Comment: As far as your `any` type goes, if you type the textarea as `let textarea = evt.target as HTMLTextAreaElement` you can remove your `string` casting for the textarea value.

Comment: Thanks. That was the type i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

**Logically, if you want 2 rows of 10 columns each, implies that you need 20 characters in total. So you can simply set `maxlength="20"`**. You may always change values accordingly...

> You don't need to use `keyup` event in this scenario. Just use `maxlength` attribute & it will limit maximum characters to take from user & won't allow more than that for you.

*See it running below -*

```css
/* disable textarea resizing */
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.0.1/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
<textarea rows="2" cols="10" maxlength="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks. but that was what i initially tried https://jsfiddle.net/p9q8jhxf/ unfortunately it does not seem to work. or am I missing something :/

Comment: Your fiddle is now working perfectly fine here -https://jsfiddle.net/p9q8jhxf/1/, you just messed to add angular environment in your fiddle. I've just updated it with one - https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.0.1/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

Comment: unfortunately not. It takes the maxlenght. but rows and cols is getting ignored. I'll keep on trying

Comment: weird. if i run the code snippet it does not work in my browser either. I can type 20 characters in the first line (tried in chrome and ie)

Comment: please let me clarify that you are running Angular 2+

Comment: Running V 7.1.2